# Convert this logic sentence to Conjunctive Normal Form

Tags: math, logic, conjunctive-normal-form, boolean-algebra

I am struggling to convert this sentence to CNF:

(A ∨ B) ⇔ (C ∧ D).

I have already tried to use the Biconditional elimination logic rule to eliminate the ⇔.

(A ∨ B) → (C ∧ D) ∧ (C ∧ D) → (A ∨ B).

Then I eliminated the → with the Implication elimination logic rule. Now I have

¬(A ∨ B) ∨ (C ∧ D) ∧ ¬(C ∧ D) ∨ (A ∨ B).

I am pretty much stuck here. My professor says I should use Distributivity rule to reduce the sentence. I can't seem to find anything that matches the requirements of Distributivity rule. So, I can't seem to use Distributivity rule before doing some logical rule that I do not know of.

What am I missing here? Can Stack Overflow help me to resume the conversion to CNF?

Comment: For ¬ before braces just make everything inside ¬ and turn the operators inside. The rest is solved by multiplying out, imagine (A+B)*(C+D) and replace by logic operators. Btw. there is a mistake: last operator needs to be an ∧

Comment: Are you sure about the mistake? I checked my work 3 times. On class notes said, Biconditional elimination logic is (a ⇔ b) ≡ ((a → b) ∧ (b → a)) and Implication elimination logic is (a → b) ≡ (¬a ∨ b).

Comment: Yes it seems to be right, excapt that you need to add braces in formula 3 around the left and right part and in formula 2 it would be better too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You began with the expression:

- (A ∨ B) ⇔ (C ∧ D).

You tried to perform the first few steps. Here I added brackets to be clear and correct:

- [(A ∨ B) → (C ∧ D)] ∧ [(C ∧ D) → (A ∨ B)]. (by definition of ⇔)
- [¬(A ∨ B) ∨ (C ∧ D)] ∧ [¬(C ∧ D) ∨ (A ∨ B)]. (by definition of →)

---

Apply the De Morgan negation law to ¬(A ∨ B) and ¬(C ∧ D):

- [(¬A ∧ ¬B) ∨ (C ∧ D)] ∧ [(¬C ∨ ¬D) ∨ (A ∨ B)].

Simplify the right half:

- [(¬A ∧ ¬B) ∨ (C ∧ D)] ∧ [¬C ∨ ¬D ∨ A ∨ B].

The distributive law for ∨ over ∧ states that: X ∨ (Y ∧ Z) ⇔ (X ∨ Y) ∧ (X ∨ Z).

We apply the law to the left half, with X = (¬A ∧ ¬B), Y = C, Z = D:

- [((¬A ∧ ¬B) ∨ C) ∧ ((¬A ∧ ¬B) ∨ D)] ∧ [¬C ∨ ¬D ∨ A ∨ B].

Apply the distributive law to two subexpressions in the left half:

- [[(¬A ∨ C) ∧ (¬B ∨ C)] ∧ [(¬A ∨ D) ∧ (¬B ∨ D)]] ∧ [¬C ∨ ¬D ∨ A ∨ B].

Remove the extra brackets because ∧ is associative and commutative:

- (¬A ∨ C) ∧ (¬B ∨ C) ∧ (¬A ∨ D) ∧ (¬B ∨ D) ∧ [¬C ∨ ¬D ∨ A ∨ B].

Rearrange the variables, and we have our **final formula** in conjunctive normal form (CNF):

- (¬A ∨ C) ∧ (¬A ∨ D) ∧ (¬B ∨ C) ∧ (¬B ∨ D) ∧ (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C ∨ ¬D).